# Redirecting the lines in to different files under a for loop in shell

Tags: shell, redirect, for-loop, append

I want to put certain lines in to two different files in a shell script. How should I put the syntax for this.

Example:

A for loop prints 6 lines, and I want that the first two lines should be appended to 1st file, and the last 4 lines should be appended to the other file.

Answer (score 0):

> A for loop prints 6 lines, and I want that the first two lines should
>   be appended to 1st file, and the last 4 lines should be appended to
>   the other file.

There is no way.  One option would be to redirect everything to a file and then copy the desired sections of the log to other files.

```
for i in {1..6}; do
  echo $i > log
done

head -4 log >> logfile1  # Appends the first four lines to logfile1
tail -2 log >> logfile2  # Appends the last two lines to logfile2
```

Comment: I was just trying some steps. I tried this:                                                            
  for((i=0;i<6;i++))           
do
if [ $i -le 1 ]
then
echo "This is line $i" >>file1
else
echo "This is line $i" >> file2
fi
done

Comment: @awrit If your input were to have known sort of input where you can determine, then saying so would work.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer

If you're using BASH you can use `tee` to send the same input to both `head -n2` and `tail -n4` at the same time using a combination of [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) and a pipe:

```
$ for i in {1..6}; do echo $i; done | tee >(head -n2 >first2.txt) | tail -n4 >last4.txt
$ cat first2.txt
1
2
$ cat last4.txt
3
4
5
6
```

#### Explanation

By default `tee` takes its STDIN and copies it to file(s) specified as arguments in addition to its STDOUT. Since process substitution returns a `/dev/fd` path to a file descriptor (`echo >(true)` to see an example) `tee` is able to write to that path like any other regular file.

Here's what the `tee` command looks like after substitution:

```
tee /dev/fd/xx | tail -n4 >last4.txt
```

Or more visually:

```
tee | tail -n4 >last4.txt
 :
 /dev/fd/xx
 :
 :..>(head -n2 >first2.txt)
```

So the output gets copied both to the `head` process (Whose output is redirected to `first2.txt`) and out STDIN which is piped to the `tail` process:

Note that process substitution is a BASH-ism, so if you're using a different shell or concerned about POSIX compliance it might not be available.